# I want to insert different array values ​per object into an array inside the object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I want to insert different array values ​​per object into an array inside the object.

I have an `arrayDetail` object.

```
console.log(arrayDetail)

[
    {
        "content": "stackoverflow1",
        "type": "one"
        "appleId": undefined 
    },
    {
        "content": "stackoverflow2",
        "type": "two"
        "appleId": undefined 
    }
]
```

I have an `applesIds` array.

```
console.log(applesIds);

[49,50]
```

This is the result I want.
I tried a few times using `map` function or `Object.fromEntries()` function and looked up other stack overflow questions,
but I can't get it to work.

```
[
    {
        "content": "stackoverflow1",
        "type": "one"
        "appleId": 49 
    },
    {
        "content": "stackoverflow2",
        "type": "two"
        "appleId": 50 
    }
]
```

Comment: `arrayDetail.forEach((v, i) => v.appleId = applesIds[i]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Array.map` (use can use other Array iteration methods as well) and update the appleId like below

```js
const arrayDetail = [{
    "content": "stackoverflow1",
    "type": "one",
    "appleId": undefined
  },
  {
    "content": "stackoverflow2",
    "type": "two",
    "appleId": undefined
  }
]
const appleIds = [49, 50];

const result = arrayDetail.map((item, index) => {
  return { ...item,
    appleId: appleIds[index]
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This would do the work

```js
let data = [
    {
        "content": "stackoverflow1",
        "type": "one",
        "appleId": undefined 
    },
    {
        "content": "stackoverflow2",
        "type": "two",
        "appleId": undefined 
    }
]

let id = [49, 50]

for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
  data[i]['appleId'] = id[i]
}

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Single liner code map always return array so i was returning array of object and put appleId with the help of index. index is 0,1,2 iteration so access id array with index

```
const mappedData = data.map((item, index) => ({ ...item, appleId: id[index] }));
```