# Set all false values ​of javascript Object to true

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, frontend

I want to select all Object arrays in selectOrderStatus and change all selected: false and true values ​​to true.

I want to set all selected object values ​​to true through the ActivateAllArrays function event when the checkbox is clicked using an input checkbox.

```
console.log(selectOrderStatus); 
const selectOrderStatus = [
    {
        selected: false,
        id: 1, 
        payment: 1234
    },
    {
        selected: false,
        id: 2, 
        payment: 12345
    },
    {
        selected: false,
        id: 3, 
        payment: 12344
    },
    {
        selected: true,
        id: 4, 
        payment: 123452
    },
    {
        selected: false,
        id: 5, 
        payment: 12341
    },
]
```

```
       <input 
              type="checkbox"
              onChange={(e) => ActivateAllArrays(e)}
            />
```

I don't know how to write code in ActivateAllArrays function. I googled all day to find it, but an error kept coming up and I had to ask.

Comment: show what you've tried and learn from your mistake

Comment: @Bravo 
I put it in a simple way in the question, but in reality, the logic is very complicated.

Comment: well, the logic you describe is very simple - so perhaps you should show your code attempts to make the logic clearer

Answer (score 1):

you've asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71776959/i-want-to-insert-different-array-values-per-object-into-an-array-inside-the-obj) before. someone already gave you a good answer involving `map`